# What drawbacks does VTP pruning pose?

Tags: switch, vlan, cisco-catalyst, networking

I'm currently learning a bit about Cisco switch configuration and VLAN configuration, specifically VTP. Reading on [Cisco's site](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/vtp/10558-21.html), the feature of VLAN pruning appears to not be used on a switch/VTP domain/VLAN by default. From what they give:

> All unknown unicasts and broadcasts in a VLAN are flooded over the entire VLAN. All switches in the network receive all broadcasts, even in situations in which few users are connected in that VLAN. VTP pruning is a feature that you use in order to eliminate or prune this unnecessary traffic.

Does it pose a specific drawback, such as certain types of traffic that may not reach their destination or higher memory use/autoconfiguration time, that makes it unfit for use in some configurations/networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access ports not in the VLAN that the unicast or broadcast originates from don't receive that traffic in the first place. That's the point of VLAN's. The excerpt from that article is making the point that instead of dealing with that traffic, if no access ports exist in the originating VLAN on a particular switch then VTP pruning "prunes" that traffic from that switch, so as to not consume trunk link bandwidth or processing cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I see it causing a problem could be an STP issue ( I can't tell without seeing a detailed diagram). If you don't have a very complex network structure, I don't think there will be any problems.